# ActiveX control not processing arrow keys correctly when hosted in Delphi application

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-2009

I have an ActiveX control hosted in our application.  The control was imported using Delphi Import component menu.

The ActiveX control contains an edit box for user input.  When I run the control in its own sandbox application(not a Delphi app) the arrow keys work as expected moving the cursor within the edit control.
However when I run my Delphi application the arrow key behaviour seems to change.  It seems to work more like a tab key instead.

I assume this is happening because of the way the VCL processes key strokes.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The control should handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` and include in the result at least `DLGC_WANTARROWS`.

In addition, if the ActiveX control is written in Delphi and is using `csReflector` in its `ControlStyle`, it should be rebuilt with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` (and any other required) message handlers added to the `TReflectorWindow` class in `AxCtrls` unit to delegate the messages to the VCL control:

```
procedure TReflectorWindow.WMKeyDown(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := FControl.Perform(Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TReflectorWindow.WMKeyUp(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := FControl.Perform(Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

This seems to be sufficient to work in my tests using D2007.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this control was not written in Delphi.  I will try hooking the WindowProc to see what is happening with the WM_GETDLGCODE message